# How to prevent jQuery .html() from escaping the href attribute automatically?

Tags: jquery, templates

**UPDATE**: Seems like a browser specific behavior as TimWolla commented - how should I normalize to the unescaped version, reliably in a cross-browser manner?

HTML:

```
<div id="test"><a href="#{one}">#{two}</a></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test').html()
=> <a href="#%7Bone%7D">#{two}</a>
```

Notice the `#{one}` in the href is escaped, while `#{two}` is not.

Is there a better way than just `unescape` the entire string?

```
unescape($('#test').html())
=> <a href="#{one}">#{two}</a>
```

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/kenn/n8veL/

Comment: Seems like it is a browser-specific issue. In Googles v8 Engine it works just fine.

Comment: That anchor appears to be a template. Why are you parsing a template to the DOM? Templates should be kept in source code (e.g. inside a SCRIPT element) and processed with JavaScript (and only *then* parsed by the browser).

Comment: TimWolla: damn! updated the question...

Comment: Šime Vidas: because the template itself is dynamic. the same partial is used to render at the server-side for some static pages, as well as templated by the js. I'm using Rails 3.2 and having ".js.coffee.erb" doesn't solve that as `render` is not accessible from the js file.

Comment: I've [updated your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/n8veL/2/) to demonstrate my answer. Firefox doesn't mess with values of other attributes, just "href" (and maybe "src" and other URL-ish things).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I doubt if there is a reliable solution to your question.  The underlying reason is simple: because the `Element.innerHTML` working underneath is non-standard and it depends solely on the browser's implementation.

If you want a reliable solution, I'd suggest you use DOM operations instead of *template*.

Comment: But that escaping is only done on the "href" attribute.  Other attributes won't be affected the same way.

Comment: @Pointy I bet some browsers (such as Firefox) escape it because the `href` is supposed to contain a URL.  So, characters not permitted to appear in it are escaped.  But still, as I said, it's browser specific and we don't have any standard to guarantee its behavior.

Comment: Right, but no browser I've tried has escaped a "data-href" attribute. It doesn't really matter where the template is kept on the element, after all.  Of course there would always be issues with HTML metacharacters in the attribute values, but for simple templates it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be performing an expansion via JavaScript on the element anyway, you can put the "href" template in a separate attribute.

```
<a href='#dummy' data-href='#{template}'>Hi</a>
```

Then just expand from the data attribute and drop the result in the real "href".

Comment: Sounds like a decent idea, but unfortunately in my case it's not so great as the same template is shared in the server-side for some static pages, and duplicate the js behavior in the server logic seems awkward.

Comment: Ah right, I see.  Well, there's probably no good work-around then other than `unescape()`.